# Fortran IIFIX unknown symbol

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have an old fortran code compiling nice using GFORTRAN.

But when I try to call a function I'm getting the follow error:

`undefined symbol: iifix`

I've found 3 occurrences of this function in the code, all of them in same context:

```
(some blah blah blah)
INTEGER*2  IWAH(24)
real*4     AH(9000)

(more blah blah blah)
iwah (3) = iifix (ah (3))

(and the blah blah blah continues...)
```

Searching for "IIFIX" I've found only "IFIX()" to convert real numbers to integer. This makes some sense to me because the variables format fits in the function purpose but .... I don't know. I have no idea what I'm doing....

How can I safely replace this function?
or ... how can I fix this error?

I'm using gfortran and my code ends with ".f90"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `integer*2` and `real*4` are not portable.  I'll ignore that issue.  What you likely want is to change `iifix(ah(3))` to `int(ah(3),2)`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. About the `integer*2` and `real*4` portability... you got me worried. Is it serious?

Comment: No, it typically isn't serious (until you use a compiler that interprets things differently).  `integer*2` is often (always?) interpreted as a 2-byte signed integer and `real*4` is a 4-byte floating point entity.  There are portable ways to get an appropriate type with the `selected_integer_kind` and `selected_real_kind` intrinsic functions.

Comment: @evets do you have a reference to iifix?

Comment: fixed kind 2 is not portable either, so integer*2 does not matter that much, that one is at least always two bytes or fails completely. One can use `kind(IWAH)` instead.

Comment: Or even (further to @VladimirF's comment), just let `=` do its job and take care of conversion.  Assuming `iifix` is indeed the non-standard intrinsic for type conversion.

Comment: `iifix` seems to come from DEC Fortran.  Documentation shows an interface of `integer*2 iifix(real*4)`.   You can find the docs by searching for _"iifix" fortran_.  The double quotes are needed with google to force matches of `iifix`